# RedisMessageListenerContainer: SubscriptionTask aborted with exception: ClassCastException

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I am using Lettuce 4.5.0 and Spring-data-redis 1.8.0. I am trying to use pub/sub with Redis 4.0 cluster using RedisMessageListenerContainer. But I am getting this error:

> RedisMessageListenerContainer: SubscriptionTask aborted with exception:
>   org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Unknown redis exception; nested exception is **java.lang.ClassCastException: com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient cannot be cast to com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisClient**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the community. The Pub/Sub functionality of Spring Data Redis 1.8 does not work with Lettuce and Redis Cluster. This is fixed with version 2.1.